# por que no me funciona el hover

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

soy nuevo programando y tengo un problema con el hover en css, trato de hacer una transicion al pasar el mouse por la pantalla y cuando lo hago no funciona, se queda el section de hola mundo y no aparece el texto del section "des", adjunto codigo de html

y adjunto el codigo del css

```css
section.menu{
        width: 400px;
        height: 33px;
        text-align: center;
        color: yellow;
        background-color: blue;}
    section.des{
        width: 400px;
        height: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: blue;
        transition: height 0.9s;
    }
    section.menu:hover section.des{
        height: 400px;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/estilo.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="menu">HOLA MUNDO</section>
        <section class="des">BLABLABLABLA</section>
    </body>
</html>
```

se agradece de antemano , muchas gracias.

Comment: No trabajo mucho con CSS, pero, ¿esto va junto `section.menu:hover section.des`?

Comment: si, los codigos que he visto, los usan juntos

Comment: ¿Ya probaste separando el `section.des` o añadiendo ~ al mismo? algo como `section.menu:hover ~ section.des`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que falta es colocarle en el codigo de hover el **simbolo de ~**  para selector de hermano general para lo ejecute, todo lo demas esta bien:

```
<style>
     section.menu{
        width: 400px;
        height: 33px;
        text-align: center;
        color: yellow;
        background-color: blue;}
    section.des{
        width: 400px;
        height: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: blue;
        transition: height 0.9s;
    }
    section.menu:hover ~ section.des{
        height: 400px;
    }
</style>
```

Te invito a que leas este link para los selectores:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

Tabla de explicacion de selectores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes Probar el codigo aqui:

```css
  section.menu{
            width: 400px;
            height: 33px;
            text-align: center;
            color: yellow;
            background-color: blue;}
        section.des{
            width: 400px;
            height: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
            background: blue;
            transition: height 0.9s;
        }
        section.menu:hover ~ section.des{
            height: 400px;
        }
```

```html
 <section class="menu">HOLA MUNDO</section>
    <section class="des">BLABLABLABLA</section>
```

Comment: muchas  gracias, funciono